# SO no longer displaying career suggestions in sidebar?

Tags: support, status-norepro, stack-overflow, jobs

I noticed that SO is no longer displaying career suggestions in the sidebar? Is this a bug, a glitch, a new "feature", a new setting I haven't enabled, ... or?

Comment: Perhaps you have an ad-blocker installed? I see the Careers 2.0 box right there [on the main questions page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions), for example.

Comment: Did you just install/enable an ad blocker?  That's an ad, not a feature of the site.

Comment: Most likely ad blocker, the job ads are there.

Comment: Ouch! I've been running ad-blockers for years - even on SO. Must be a new rule that obviously was installed in the background. Thanks, case closed.